# Postgis - ST_DWithin performance, again

Tags: performance, postgresql, postgis, gis

I have an example table called global_points of 5 million records with random geography points.

I've created an index with `CREATE INDEX global_points_gix ON public.global_points USING gist (location);`

I executed a geography (not geometry) search by polygon:

```
SELECT count(*) from global_points 
WHERE ST_DWithin(location, 'SRID=4326; POLYGON((0 0, 50 0, 50 50, 0 0))', 0);
```

Execution of this query takes ~30 sec on my computer (hdd, 2 cores 2.8GHz, 8GB ram).

I've tried some tricks (e.g. put polygon definition in a separate table :

```
SELECT  count(*)
FROM global_points a , polygons b
WHERE ST_DWithin(b.location,a.location ,5e-05) and b.id=2;
```

but this made no significant performance improvement.

I also executed this search on the table without an index, but again with no difference for the above polygon table. For a smaller indexed polygon table the query is faster.

It is possible to do anything else to improve performance? I know that geographic search is complicated, but indexing should improve search speed.

Comment: Post the explanation plan. And the reason for using geography just to avoid the "use geometry" comments.

Comment: "Random geometric points". Are you sure they have valid values? If you have used SELECT ADDGEOMETRY, the check will be done implicitly. So, please post the table definition, constraints etc... What SRID are those points? And also what does the third value 0 in ST_DWITHIN? You want to find those with distance 0? And how this works for polygons and points?

Comment: Is there an index on id? If not, you might be doing a full table scan -- impossible to tell without seeing output of explain, as Jakub says.